# Edge detection in dark images with background noise

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have many images from a high-speed camera that I would like to analyze. In the first step, I want to recognize the edges of a wiper, but I have problems recognizing them automatically because they are only displayed negatively, i.e. they are black in the image.[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnAxY.jpg)

I have tried to output the straight lines via canny and HoupHLinesP using the cv2 library or, in another attempt, to display the gradient transitions via Sobel and then to display the straight lines again via canny and HoupHLinesP in the gradient image. Furthermore, I have varied the thresholds of HoupHLines but have the problem that I get many lines displayed that I do not want and those that I want are not displayed. Several lines are displayed that are very close to each other or parts of the lines I want are not displayed. In addition, the straight lines do not lie perfectly on the edge, as you can see from the straight line on the right. Furthermore, I have to adjust the thresholds for the individual image so that all straight lines are visible. If I adjust the thresholds automatically until only x straight lines are visible, the desired ones are often not included.
[Image Sobel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL7Yn.png)
[Image with detected lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQVYq.png)

Ideally, the whole thing should work in such a way that at the end only the right and left straight lines are output and the edge in the middle is hidden and the whole thing can be done for all images without manual adjustment.

Does anyone have any ideas on how this could be implemented or are there other commands or libraries that do the job better?

Here is a code example of one of my attempts:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def is_vertical_line(x1, y1, x2, y2, angle_threshold=5):
    """Überprüft, ob eine Linie innerhalb des angegebenen Winkelbereichs senkrecht ist."""
    angle = np.degrees(np.arctan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1))
    angle = abs(angle) % 180
    return abs(angle - 90) <= angle_threshold


image = cv2.imread('F:\Studienarbeit\Testdaten\SourceDaten\DEG_30kgh_8mbar_250rpm_110grad_HD2bar_Img000087.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


sobelx = cv2.Sobel(gray, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
abs_sobelx = np.absolute(sobelx)
sobelx_8u = np.uint8(abs_sobelx)
edges = cv2.Canny(sobelx_8u, 5, 250, apertureSize=3)



lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, threshold=5, minLineLength=250, maxLineGap=40)

image_with_lines = image.copy()
if lines is not None:
    for line in lines:
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
        if is_vertical_line(x1, y1, x2, y2):
            cv2.line(image_with_lines, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 0, 255), 2)



plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(cv2.convertScaleAbs(sobelx_8u), cmap='gray')
plt.title('Sobel Gradient')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_with_lines, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('HoughLinesP')

plt.show()
```

Here are a few pictures that show how the wiper moves through the picture(Beween the first and the last picture are 7 pictures that are not shown here):
[image]

[image]

[image]

Image when it is slightly rotated:
[image]

Comment: can you show pictures that demonstrate in what ways the "wiper" can move?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yea sure here are three pictures

Comment: Why should the "edge" in the middle be hidden? It looks every bit as real to me as the two outer blade edges. You seem to have plenty of signal to noise in the best lit parts of the image it should be relatively easy to track the three lines. You can ignore the middle one of the three if you like but you can't blame the software for detecting it! The left hand edge looks (measures)  concave to me but it could be an artefact caused by scattering inside your lens. The other edges look fairly vertical and clean.

Comment: so these two dark bars always move across this "spotlight" kinda thing? how much info do you need out of this? just the horizontal position of this two-bar object? that's fairly doable, as long as this thing is visible. -- Mark Setchell suggests a good approach. you just need to make sure that pair of bars stays aligned to the axes

Comment: @MartinBrown The edge in the middle is not relevant for my evaluation. I am of course aware that the software is not interested in this, but I am not quite sure how to delete the recognized line. The fact that the edges are slightly concave is because the reflecting surface is concave (the light comes from the camera).

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz In the first step, only the determination of the edges is important to scale the image, since it is known how wide the bars are in reality. In the next step, a liquid is propelled by the beams, or rather by the roller, and the area that is propelled is to be determined

Comment: A simple hack would be to reject any line found that is closer to an edge than 1.5x the width of your dark blades (or simply allow it to find three lines and just ignore the middle column). I think you do have a systematic error or distortion when in the edge nearest the brightest part of the illuminator the blades in the first two images under the sourcecode bend the other way (ie away from the bright light).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it helps if you sum the pixels down the columns. I did that and appended the result at the bottom.

[image]

It's just convert to greyscale, then :

```
colSums = np.sum(image, axis=0)
```

Or, you may fare better using `np.mean(image, axis=0)` if your images vary in height and you want to set a threshold.

Comment: Somehow I hadn't thought of that yet. That's very helpful. Unfortunately, the camera is not always perfectly aligned and the images are often slightly rotated and would have to be rotated first(added a picture of it). My approach would be to make an edge definition and then determine straight lines that are approximately vertical and then determine the average gradient and then rotate the image. But maybe you have a better and simpler solution.